# Oracle SQL Developer - dbms_output.put_line not working

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using [Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/) because my class requires it and I don't have a choice.

I would like to print some things.

```
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('asdf');
END;
```

it doesn't work. it just says `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

[image]

SQL developer even helpfully greys it out:

[image]

please advise.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Developer, type `set serveroutput on` and execute it once. You can remove it after that. It will display DBMS output for that session.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out dbms output appears in another window you need to enable.

- enable the pane `View -> DBMS Output`
- click the green `+` to actually connect
- re-run your script

[source](https://www.databasestar.com/sql-developer-dbms_output/)